# Is there a flatpak runtime that contains java?

Tags: linux, flatpak, flatpak-builder

I'm currently trying to convert my java project into a flatpak package.
But, in order to run the .jar file i need java which looks like isn't part of the freedesktop runtime.
Is there any runtime that comes with java or do I have to make the jdk part of my flatpak package?

Comment: `flatpak search java` yields a bunch of results. I don't if some of those are actually the JDK or not, but you could simply look at how one of the existing Java-requiring flatpaks is put together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
There are extensions for the freedesktop sdk starting with org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension. With the help of [this openjdk11 extension](https://github.com/flathub/org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.openjdk11), I was able to correctly add the jre to my flatpak package

Comment: How to first disconnect the extension e.g. `org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.openjdk` of the application `com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community`. Because when try to uninstall the extension an alert is showed there informing that the `extension openjdk` is used by the `IntelliJ app`.